# Legendre Polynomial Termination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, legendre-polynomials

I've been reviewing Legendre Polynomials for problems in electrostatics recently, and I came across something that I hadn't thought of the first time. So for the function to be well behaved on the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, we want the series with the coefficients:

$$ a_{n+2} = \frac{n(n+1)-l(l+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} a_n $$

to terminate for some $n$. The first, most obvious solution is that the series terminates when $n=l$ if $l$ is a positive integer. However if we send $l \rightarrow -(l+1)$, then the equation remains unchanged (which makes sense since this is the other root to the equation $n(n+1) - l(l+1) = 0$). Why then does every author (that I've encountered or been able to find) say that $l$ must be a positive integer? Is it just because using $-(l+1)$ would be equivalent to using negative integers as well so we choose to restrict ourselves to the positive integers? Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Replacing $l$ by $-1-l$ will give the same polynomial. Similar kind of situation holds for Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

Comment: Only the value of $l(l+1)$ is relevant. So nothing is gained by replacing $l$ with $-l-1$ because $(-l-1)(-l-1+1)=(-l-1)(-l)=l(l+1)$. And you're looking for solutions where the series truncates, which is where $n \ge 0$ and $n(n+1)=l(l+1)$, which is not changed by replacing $l$ with $-l-1$. Keep in mind that you're only looking for a series where $n \ge 0$.